# Два работяги или две работяги?

Tags: согласование

Два работяги или две работяги? Как согласовывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**РАБОТЯГА,** -и; м. и ж. Разг. 1. Работящий, трудолюбивый человек (употр. обычно как похвала). Всю жизнь был настоящим работягой. 2. Рабочий человек, простой труженик. Он простой работяга.

Итак, работяга может относиться и к двум женщинам, и двум мужчинам: ***два работяги, две работяги.***

Если известен их женский или мужской пол, то берется нужная форма. Если пол разный, то выбирается **мужской род**.

Comment: Это речь об автобусах....

Comment: Автобус – это мужской род, два работяги.  Других вариантов у этого сочетания нет. Значение переносное, метафорическое.